# WebWorkers and Asynchronous shared data access. How in Scala.js?

Tags: javascript, scala, asynchronous, web-worker, scala.js

Please consider a Scala.js class that contains a large JavaScript [typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) called *xArr*.

A process called  **p(*xArr*)** consumes *xArr* as input but takes a long time to complete.  In order to avoid script timeout warnings, **p(*xArr*)** runs in a Web Worker.

Recall these constraints on communication between the main thread and the Web Worker thread:

1. Communication in either direction takes the form of [message passing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage).
2. Message data must conform to the requirements of JavaScript's [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm).
3. Unless specified in the optional transfer list, message data gets duplicated instead of transfered to/from the main and Worker threads.
4. To transfer message data instead of copying it to/from the worker thread, the data must implement the [Transferable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Transferable) interface and the transfer list must contain a reference to the transferable data.
5. If a transferable object transfers between threads, the sending thread loses access to it.

Because of *xArr*'s size, sending a copy of it to the worker thread will incur severe memory costs, but becasue of **p(*xArr*)**'s run time, it can not run in the main thread.

*Fortunately*, typed arrays implement the Transferable interface, so to save compute and memory resources, the program invokes **p(*xArr*)** by transferring *xArr* to the WebWorker which invokes **p(*xArr*)** then transfers *xArr* back to the main thread.

*Unfortunately*, other asynchronous methods in the main thread must access *xArr* which may have transferred to the worker's scope at invocation time.

What Scala language features could govern access to *xArr* so that method calls execute immediately when the main thread owns *xArr* but wait for it to return to scope when the worker owns *xArr*?

In other words: **How would you handle a class variable that continuously alternates between *defined* and *undefined* over time?**

Would you suggest locks?  Promise/Callback queues?  Would you approach the problem in an entirely different way?  If so, how?

Remember that this is a Scala.js library, so we must disqualify JVM specific features.

Answer (score 2):

I understand your very real pain here. This used to work with [SharedArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SharedArrayBuffer) but it is currently disabled in Chrome. Sadly there is no alternative for shared memory:

> Note that SharedArrayBuffer was disabled by default in all major browsers on 5 January, 2018 in response to Spectre.

There are plans to re-add `SharedArrayBuffer` after proper security auditing will be complete. I guess we'll have to wait.

If you were running your code in Node - this would be hard but possible.

Comment: Benjamin, thanks for breaking the ice, and for the validation.
Would you agree that SharedArrayBuffer adds new problems and solves none?
From your link:  "... and a side effect to the block in one agent will eventually become visible in the other agent. ... Depending on the system ... it can take a while until the change is propagated to all contexts."
Does it duplicate data and propagates changes?  If so, that violates the memory constraint.  If not and the contexts share access to common data, won't we suffer the concurrency issues that always plague multi-threaded shared mutable state?

Comment: I agree it adds new problems but it also solves some. Namely the need for shared memory sometimes. Regretfully it's a moot discussion at this point since SharedArrayBuffer is disabled and what you (and I) want to do is currently impossible due to Sceptre.  SharedArrayBuffer is explicitly opting into unsafe shared memory for performance (which I understand you were looking to do) there are locks and other (regular) tools and I admit it's not a very common use case - which is why it's so easy for them to keep it disabled. I'm sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: As for validation - you are entirely correct in everything your post says - both in how `Transferable` works, structured cloning (which was removed recently - see note in 2.9.9 in the spec but is still de-facto there) and the fact there is no way to share memory (except the now-disabled SharedArrayBuffer). This is not something Scala can solve without the web exposing the _capability_ to do so. Your one "out" is web assembly which will _eventually_ support shared memory and threads.

Comment: I believe we have some tools to get around this now.  We have Akka.js, locks, futures, promises, callbacks, and old fashioned javascript events.  Let's explore some design ideas.

Comment: Sorry, anything that runs in browsers fundamentally builds on the web platform. It’s not JavaScript’s fault (this time!) - it’s the web platform which Scala.js shares.

Comment: (Unless shared memory is not a requirement)

Comment: How about take turns memory instead of shared?  The transferable array can pass between the main and worker threads.  Could we find a trick to delay main thread computations on the data when the worker has control of it?

Comment: Suppose each method call returns a future.  Then, when invoked while the main thread has the data, the futures complete right away, but if invoked while the worker has the data, the method calls queue and complete when the worker returns the data back to the main thread?

Comment: What kind of code could track the state of the transferable class variable?  How does it signal the events of the data's arrivals and departures?  How does it govern the queue of deferred method calls?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170102/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-ben-mckenneby).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to all who considered this issue.  A solution exists as of 19 May 2018; hopefully a better one can replace it soon.

The current version works as follows:

**Problem 1: How can we associate function calls from the main thread with function definitions in the worker thread?**

S1: A map of Promise objects:  `Map[Long, PromiseWrapper]()` associates a method invocation ID with a promise that can process the result.  [This simple multiplexing mechanism evolved from another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44348491/how-to-wrap-web-worker-response-messages-in-futures).  Thanks again to [Justin du Coeur](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1245509/justin-du-coeur).

**Problem 2: How can we invoke functions in the worker thread from the main thread?**

S1: Pass a text representation of the function to the worker, then parse it with eval and invoke the resulting function.  Unfortunately, [eval comes with security risks](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/94017/what-are-the-security-issues-with-eval-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).  Besides, having to write pure JavaScript code in string values defeats most of the advantages of Scala.js, namely type safety and Scala syntax.

S2: Storing function definitions in a lookup table in worker scope and invoking the functions by passing the keys.  This could work, but feels clunky in Scala because different functions take parameters that vary in number and type.

S3: Wrap the functions into serializable case classes, then send the serialized bytes from the main scope to the worker scope and invoke the function there.  You can think of these case classes as message classes.  The current solution uses this approach.  It relies on [BooPickle](https://github.com/suzaku-io/boopickle) by [Otto Chrons](https://github.com/ochrons).  The serialized class wraps the method call and any trivial function parameters, e.g. numbers, short strings, and simple case classes.  Large data, like the TypedArray values featured in this question transfer from the main thread to the worker thread through a mechanism discussed later.  Unfortunately, this approach means that all operations on the TypedArray values must be defined before compile time because BooPickle relies on macros, not reflection, to serialize and deserialize classes.

**Problem 3: How can we pass the values of the TypedArray class variable, *xArr* to and from the worker thread without duplicating it?**

S1: Because xArr conforms to the Transferrable interface, it can transfer wholly between the main and worker scopes.  At the same time, the serialized classes that wrap the function calls conform to a trait that specifies an apply method with this signature:

`def apply(parameters: js.Array[Transferable]): js.Array[Transferable]`

By convention, the parameters array contains a serialized version of the message case class in index 0.  Subsequent indices contain the TypedArray values.  Each message class has its own unique implementation of this apply method.

**Problem 4: How can we pass the result of the computation back to the promise that waits for it in the main thread?**

S1: The apply methods mentioned in Problem 3.S1 return a new array of Transferrable objects with another serialized message class at its head.  That message class wraps the return value from the computation: **p(*xArr*)** and, with an apply method of its own, instructs the main thread on how to interpret the array.  In cases where **p(*xArr*)** returns large objects like other TypedArray values, those occupy subsequent positions in the array.

**Problem 5: What if statements in the main thread try to access *xArr* when it has transferred to the worker thread?**

S1.  Now, any code in the main thread can only access *xArr* through a checkOut method and must restore it by calling a checkIn method.  The checkOut method returns a Future that completes when xArr returns from the worker thread.  Concurrent calls to checkOut get pushed onto a queue of promises.  Any code that calls checkOut must call checkIn to pass control of *xArr* on to the next Promise waiting in the queue.  Unfortunately, this design burdens the programmer with the responsibility of restoring *xArr* to its encompassing class.  Unfortunately, schemes like this resemble classical concurrency models with [locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) and memory allocation methods like [malloc and free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119134/how-do-malloc-and-free-work), and tend toward buggy code that freezes or crashes.

**Problem 5: After p(*xArr*) executes in the worker thread, how can *xArr* return to the class that encapsulated it in the main thread?**

S1.  Message case classes meant to invoke **p(*xArr*)** now inherit from a trait called Boomerang.  As the name implies, these messages transfer from the main thread to the worker thread, invoke **p(*xArr*)** while there, then return, unchanged, to the main thread.  Once returned to the main thread, Boomerang objects call relevant checkIn methods to restore *xArr* values to their original encapsulating objects.

For simplicity, this answer leaves out details about different types of Transferrable parameters, operations that mutate xArr instead of simply reading it and restoring it, operations that don't take any parameters but still yield large TypedArray responses, and operations that take multiple large TypedArray parameters, but minor modifications to the five solutions articulated above met those objectives.

With this as a baseline, can we:

**Simplify this design?**

**Incorporate user defined operations?**

**Find safer alternatives to the checkOut, checkIn methods?**